# Android Screenshot OpenGL + Native GUI

Tags: android, opengl-es, screenshot

I'm trying to take a **screenshot** of an activity containing **openGL** elements (from unity with vuforia... so the openGL code is auto-generated and not very accesible) and **custom native layouts** (buttons and so).

Currently I'm using the method:

```
ViewGroup v1 = (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(id).getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap source = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
sCoverBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, statusBarHeight,
  source.getWidth(), source.getHeight() - statusBarHeight);
```

In a root view containing the openGL and the other layouts, but the openGL (unity) area is completely black.

Comment: Did you get an answer? If yes can you please share it. I'm kinda stuck with the same problem.